# OpenLayers Bind Dynamic Checkbox Creation to GeoServer LayerGroup

Tags: jquery, openlayers

Morning all,

Ok, so...I've been playing around with Geoserver, JQuery & OpenLayers and making some great progress. I'm running into a small issue.

I have Layergroups within GeoServer and I'm serving them to the HTML page by running the GeoServer REST API (http://:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/riskdatasuite/layergroups.json) which returns the list of Layergroups within Geoserver. I'm then dynamically creating *n* checkboxes matching the number of Layergroups (the idea being if I add a new Layergroup it's immediately available as a checkbox option within the HTML page). It also adds it to the map immediately. This works nicely (using the code below):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var inputs = [], i
  var riskLayers = []

  $.getJSON(_geoserverConfig.geoserver_url_layergroup, function (result) {

    var lgArray = result.layerGroups.layerGroup
    inputs.push('<ul class="layerlist_sort">');
    $.each(lgArray, function (index, value) {

      inputs.push('<li><input type="checkbox" id="' + index + '" name="' + value.name + '" checked>' + value.name + ' Flood</input></li>')

      var riskLayer = new TileLayer({
        source: new TileWMS({
          url: _geoserverConfig.geoserver_url_wms,
          params: { 'LAYERS': value.name, 'TILED': true, },
          serverType: 'geoserver',
          crossOrigin: null
        })
      });
      riskLayers = riskLayer;
      map.addLayer(riskLayer)
    });

    inputs.push('</ul>');
    $('#layerList').append(inputs.join(''))

    // map.addLayer(riskLayers)
  });

});
```

I then setup up this bit of code:

```
  $(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {

  var layer = $(this).attr("name")
  // this will contain a reference to the checkbox   
  if (this.checked) {
    layer.setVisible(true);
  } else {
    // the checkbox is now no longer checked
    layer.setVisible(false);

  }
})
```

So the idea is the name value corresponds with the create TileLayer. I'm trying to link the checkbox to that created TileLayer so I can set the visibility true/false...but clearly it's not working and I've done something wrong. The checkboxes appear and tick on/off but it is not even executing the

`$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function ()`

as even if I put a `windows.alert('Checkbox Test');` within the checkbox function it's not alerting me.

Part of me is wondering if there is a sequence issue whereby the checkboxes are being created after the document is ready and there is a disconnect. I'm also sure that my use of setVisible is not correct either. I'm using the name value of the checkbox to correspond with the actual TileLayer which I'm sure I'm doing incorrectly.

Any advice would be grately appreciated! 
Cheers,
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple improve to you code would be to use a dictionary with `layer name` as key and `layer object` as value, something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var inputs = [], i
  var riskLayers = {} // <- instead of array a dictionary

  $.getJSON(_geoserverConfig.geoserver_url_layergroup, function (result) {

    var lgArray = result.layerGroups.layerGroup
    inputs.push('<ul class="layerlist_sort">');
    $.each(lgArray, function (index, value) {

      inputs.push('<li><input type="checkbox" id="' + index + '" name="' + value.name + '" checked>' + value.name + ' Flood</input></li>')

      var riskLayer = new TileLayer({
        source: new TileWMS({
          url: _geoserverConfig.geoserver_url_wms,
          params: { 'LAYERS': value.name, 'TILED': true, },
          serverType: 'geoserver',
          crossOrigin: null
        })
      });
      riskLayers[value.name] = riskLayer; // <- add the layer to the dictionary
      map.addLayer(riskLayer)
    });

    inputs.push('</ul>');
    $('#layerList').append(inputs.join(''))

  });

});
```

And then, on the checkbox events just do this,

```
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
  var chkProp = $(this).prop('checked'); 
  var layerN = $(this).attr("name")  
  if(riskLayers.hasOwnProperty(layerN)){
      riskLayers[layerN].setVisible(chkProp);
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Apologies for the late acceptance. Took me a while to get back to it.

Comment: Glad it help you!.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution but I hardly think it's a good one: I decided I could loop through the maplayers and match the *name* property in the checkbox with the created layer. Since they were created from the same source this match would work...it's not elegant or very nice but it does work: If there is a better way please let me know :)

```
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {

  var chkProp = $(this).prop('checked'); 
  var layerN = $(this).attr("name")

  var mapLayers = map.getLayers().getArray();  
    mapLayers.forEach(function (layer) {
        var v = layer.values_.source.params_;
        if  (typeof(v) != 'undefined')
        {
          if(v.LAYERS === layerN)
          {
              layer.setVisible(chkProp);              
          }          
        }
      });
    });
```